# Rule to calculate power of a number when the exponent is Negative in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, exponentiation

I have a power function `pow` that attempts to calculate the value of `B` to the power of  `E`. So far I handle the cases-
1. exponent is 0
2. exponent is non-zero

```
pow(B,0,1).
pow(B,E,Result):-   E2 is E - 1,
                    pow(B,E2,Result2),
                    Result is B*Result2.
```

How can I add another case where the power function can handle negative exponents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, one should consider how to define 0<sup>0</sup>. Formally speaking it is *indeterminate*. It could be zero or it could be 1. As Wolfram's Mathworld says in its [article on powers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Power.html) and in its [article on zero](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Zero.html):

> 0<sup>0</sup> (zero to the zeroth power) itself is undefined. The lack of a well-defined meaning for this quantity follows from the mutually contradictory facts that *a*<sup>0</sup> is always 1, so 0<sup>0</sup> should equal 1, but 0<sup>*a*</sup> is always 0 (for *a* > 0), so 0<sup>*a*</sup> should equal 0. The choice of definition for 0<sup>0</sup> is usually defined to be indeterminate, although defining 0<sup>0</sup> = 1 allows some formulas to be expressed simply (Knuth 1992; Knuth 1997, p. 57).

So you should first choose how to define the special case of 0<sup>0</sup>: Is it 0? Is it 1? Is it undefined?

I choose to look at it as being undefined.

That being said, you can look at a positive exponent as indicated repeated multiplication (e.g. 10<sup>3</sup> is 10*10*10, or 1,000), and you can look at a negative exponent as indicating repeated division (e.g, 10<sup>-3</sup> is (((1/10)/10)/10), or 0.001). My inclination, partly because I like the symmetry of this approach and partly to avoid the cuts (since a cut is often a signal that you've not defined the solution properly), would be something like this:

```
% -----------------------------
% The external/public predicate
% -----------------------------
pow( 0 , 0 , _ ) :- ! , fail .
pow( X , N , R ) :-
  pow( X , N , 1 , R )
  .

% -----------------------------------
% the tail-recursive worker predicate
% -----------------------------------
pow( _ , 0 , R , R  ).
pow( X , N , T , R  ) :-
  N > 0 ,
  T1 is T * X ,
  N1 is N-1   ,
  pow( X , N1 , T1 , R )
  .
pow( _ , 0 , R , R  ) :-
  N < 0 ,
  T1 is T / X ,
  N1 is N+1   ,
  pow( X , N1 , T1 , R )
  .
```

The other approach, as others have noted, is to define a positive exponent as indicating repeated multiplication, and a negative exponent as indicating the reciprocal of the positive exponent, so 10<sup>3</sup> is 10*10*10 or 1,000, and 10<sup>-3</sup> is 1/(10<sup>3</sup>), or 1/1,000 or 0.001. To use this definition, I'd again avoid the cuts and do something like this:

```
% -----------------------------
% the external/public predicate
% -----------------------------
pow( 0 , 0 , _ ) :-  % 0^0 is indeterminate. Is it 1? Is it 0? Could be either.
  ! ,
  fail
  .
pow( X , N , R ) :-
  N > 0 ,
  pow( X , N , 1 , R )
  .
pow( X , N , R ) :-
  N < 0 ,
  N1 = - N ,
  pow( X , N1 , 1 , R1 ) ,
  R is 1 / R1
  .

% -----------------------------------
% The tail-recursive worker predicate
% -----------------------------------
pow( _ , 0 , R , R  ).
pow( X , N , T , R  ) :-
  N > 0 ,
  T1 is T * X ,
  N1 is N-1   ,
  pow( X , N1 , T1 , R )
  .
```

Comment: I really appreciate the time and care you took to write down such a clear and comprehensive answer. Also, I personally consider 0^0 as undefined, although I understand there are different ways to look at it. For anyone stumbling onto this read - http://www.askamathematician.com/2010/12/q-what-does-00-zero-raised-to-the-zeroth-power-equal-why-do-mathematicians-and-high-school-teachers-disagree/

Answer (score 2):

To start, your second clause is non tail recursive (you can read about the subject [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)). It means that eventually, you will run out of call stack memory when running it.
A good thing would be to use an accumulator to make it tail recursive. You can achieve that as follows :

```
% we add an accumulator to poW/3, making it pow/4.
pow(B, E, Result) :- pow(B, E, 1, Result).

% when we hit 0, our accumulator holds B^E so we unify it with result.
pow(_, 0, Accu, Accu) :- !.

% at each step, we multiply our accumulator by B
pow(B, E, Accu, Result) :-
    NewE is E - 1,
    NewAccu is Accu * B,
    pow(B, NewE, NewAccu, Result).
```

Then, you can simply handle the negative case by adding this clause on top of the others (it simply tells prolog that a negative power is the inverse of the positive one) :

```
pow(B, E, Result) :-
    E < 0,
    PositiveE is - E,
    pow(B, PositiveE, 1, R),
    !,
    Result is 1 / R.
```

Note that you can do it directly with your code :

```
pow(B, E, Result) :-
    E < 0,
    PositiveE is - E,
    pow(B, PositiveE, R),
    !,
    Result is 1 / R.
```

Plus, we now introduced a very red cut (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28logic_programming%29#Red_cut) for the meaning of red cut if necessary). So it'd be better to turn into a green cut with this modification :

```
pow(B, E, Result) :-
    E < 0,
    PositiveE is - E,
    pow(B, PositiveE, 1, R),
    !,
    Result is 1 / R.

% we add an accumulator to poW/3, making it pow/4.
pow(B, E, Result) :-
    E >= 0, %************* HERE *****************
    pow(B, E, 1, Result).

% when we hit 0, our accumulator holds B^E so we unify it with result.
pow(_, 0, Accu, Accu) :- !.

% at each step, we multiply our accumulator by B
pow(B, E, Accu, Result) :-
    NewE is E - 1,
    NewAccu is Accu * B,
    pow(B, NewE, NewAccu, Result).
```

Comment: That was very informative. Thanks!! (esp. for the non tail recursive and red cut concepts .. )

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that `a^(2b) = (a^b)^2` and `x^2 = x*x`. It is ok to call a tail-recursive working predicate with accumulator, in a non-tail fashion, from a top-level "UI" predicate. That way you don't have to implement working predicate for negative powers but rather reuse the one for positive power, and alter its result in the top-level predicate (I see this has already been suggested):

```
pow(B, E, R):- E<0 -> ... ; E=:=0 -> ... ; E>0 -> ... .
```