# Prolog Functor - Computing x^y

Tags: prolog, exponentiation, iso-prolog

I am new to prolog and trying out to learn how to program. I want to know how to compute `x^y` in Prolog both being integers.

I know for a fact that it goes something like this:

```
% exp(y,x,z) <- z is x**y
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240952/rule-to-calculate-power-of-a-number-when-the-exponent-is-negative-in-prolog/8241403#8241403

Comment: please use predicate instead of functor btw.

Comment: Thanks @Mog interesting answer there. I also want to know how to test it in GNU Prolog. Any help please? Thanks!

Comment: Well I do not see any non standard predicate used so you can test it as is. If you need basic advice about how to compile / consult a file in gnu prolog many tutorials are available and google should help you just as quickly as I would.

Comment: Thanks I got to know how to do it.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
?- [user].
exp(X,Y,Z) :- Z is round(X**Y).

Yes
?- exp(3,4,R).
R = 81
```

Difference to your solution:

1) The (:-)/2 operator is usually used in Prolog to define rules and not the (->)/2 operator.

2) (* * )/2 yields a float. There are a couple of possibilties to convert a float to
a integer. Besides floor/1 and truncate/1, the round/1 function probably works best
here sind the result of (**)/2 might not be precise.

Bye

P.S.: There is a proposal for a native integer power function, it would use the operator
(^)/2. For more information see:

http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#pow

The native power function might yield better results where the above implementation might run into an overflow or imprecise results. Here is an example with different results (SWI Prolog 5.11.33):

?- X is round(123.0**45.0).
X = 11110408185131957010659080963921001637101840276079092263812695592440203675146350059871151325184.

?- X is 123^45.
X = 11110408185131956285910790587176451918559153212268021823629073199866111001242743283966127048043.

Comment: The proposal for `(^)/2` has now become a standard!