# How to get this Prolog program to work

Tags: prolog, logic, declarative

I am currently trying to create a program that takes two inputs a base and an exponent, so basically im going to ask for those two things for example if the user of Prolog inputs base 2 and exponent 3, I want it to return 8.., Here is what I got so far, and doesnt work:

```
base:- write('Input the base: '),read(X),expo(X).
exponent:- write('Input the exponent '),read(Y),expo(Y).


expo(X,Y):- A is Y*Y,B is A*X,write(B).
```

**HELP PLEASE**

Comment: _Doesn't work_ is nearly useless as debugging advice goes; _what_ doesn't work? What output do you get? What output do you expect? Why does your `expo(A,B):-` appear to define a rule that takes two parameters, but your `base:-` and `exponent:-` appear to call it with just one parameter?

Answer (score 5):

- You've defined `expo/2` (i.e. a predicate `expo` with two arguments), but you're calling `expo/1`.
- The way you've split up your `read/1` calls into different predicates means `X` and `Y` are in different scopes; you'll never be able to call `expo(X,Y)` unless you put `read(X)` and `read(Y)` within the same rule.
- Your exponentiation definition is wrong. X^Y is not Y*Y*X. If you're required to implement this yourself, you'll need a recursive predicate to do it. If not, use the built-in exponentiation operator, `X**Y`.

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240952/rule-to-calculate-power-of-a-number-when-the-exponent-is-negative-in-prolog) to see how to implement pow correctly. For the input part, you might want to consider not to bother implementing it until your `pow/
3` predicate works. To test this predicate, you can just use `?- pow(2, 3, R).` in the meantime.

And Prolog should answer with `R = 8.`.

And as said in a previous answer, the input part is wrong. But this previous answer already gave sufficient leads about how to better the situation so I'll leave it at that.